# Tengo un problema con un arraylist<> en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-adapter

Soy algo nuevo en Android y estoy haciendo una app en donde se usa una lista de datos sacados de firebase, la cual la quiero mostrar en un recyclerView y no me lo muestra directamente, pero al debuguear busco el error y con ciertos pasos me muestra la lista pero con la app alentada, quizá el error esté en el adaptador o al momento de bajar la info de la base de datos. Este es el código en donde no me muestra la lista:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

ArrayList<Item> listaItems = new ArrayList<>();
//Aquí declaro mi adaptador y le doy la lista
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,getListaItems());
//Método que obtiene la lista de objetos
public ArrayList<Item> getListaItems()
{
    db.collection("Historias")
            .get()
//Al debuguear, se detiene en esta linea y salta hasta el return, dando como resultado un 0 cuando se recibe en el adaptador.
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Map<String, Object> historias = new HashMap<>();
                            historias = document.getData();
                            String titulo = (String)historias.get("Titulo");
                            String contenido = (String)historias.get("Historia");
                            String usuario = (String)historias.get("Usuario");

                            listaItems.add(
                                    new Item(
                                            titulo,
                                            contenido,
                                            usuario
                                    )
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(historias.this, "No se pudo actualizar las historias porque... "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    return listaItems;
}
```

Clase del adaptador:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> listaItem;
//Al recibir el Array listaItem aquí me da cero
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> listaItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listaItem = listaItem;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_lista, null);
    System.out.println("CREATE VIEW HOLDER : " + i);
    return new Holder(contentView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Item item = listaItem.get(i);
    Holder holder = (Holder) viewHolder;
    holder.titulo.setText(item.getTitulo());
    holder.historia.setText(item.getHistoria());
    holder.usuario.setText(item.getUsuario());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return listaItem.size();}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView titulo, usuario, historia;

    public Holder(View v) {
        super(v);

        titulo = v.findViewById(R.id.ilTitulo);
        historia = v.findViewById(R.id.ilHistoria);
        usuario = v.findViewById(R.id.ilUsuario);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Item item = new Item(

                        titulo.getText().toString(),
                        historia.getText().toString(),
                        usuario.getText().toString()

                );
                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        item.getTitulo() + "\n" +
                                item.getHistoria() + "\n" +
                                item.getUsuario(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a resolver el por qué no me lo muestra correctamente.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Si, como parece, tienes un modelo `Item` con los mismos atributos de tus documentos de Firebase, no necesitas usar el map, simplemente los puedes recuperar así dentro del bucle `for`: **`Item item = document.toObject(Item.class);`** Y a continuación lo agregas a la lista: **`listaItems.add(item);`**. Luego usas `listaItems` para llenar el `RecyclerView`. No tienes que marear tanto los datos usando un map. Lee el apartado: [Obtén datos con Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). Si no te muestra nada al menos verifica la lista.

Comment: Si tiene razón, le estaba dando muchas vueltas, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, por alguna razón, esta línea no deja que llegue al bucle for:
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

Que es en la parte del método donde obtengo los documentos de firebase.

Answer (score 0):

amigo te dejo una explicación para que entiendas el problema. Sino puedes descifrar por qué no anda, en la semana me desocupo y te traigo un ejemplo. Tu método getListaItems retorna la lista vacía porque estás llamando a una request de firebase que se ejecutan de manera asincrónica. Es decir, va a realizar el pedido a firebase y recién cuando los datos estén (o haya fallado) se va a ejecutar onComplete y para ese entonces ya vas a haber retornado la lista sin nada (es por eso que el debugger te salta a esa línea y en el adapter dices que tiene cero elementos. A esto voy con que no puedes retornar un valor a partir de un llamado a firebase, puedes en el mismo onComplete completar la lista como ya lo haces y notificar al adapter que se agregaron elementos. El resto debiera andar.

Resumiendo:
getListItems debiera retornar void
y luego del for en onComplete notifica a tu adapter 
Utiliza el debugger con un breakpoint ya dentro del onComplete a ver si se ejecuta y si levantas bien los valores. 
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,getListaItems()); //En esta línea cambia la función por el atributo listaItems.

Espero que te sirva, luego de que rinda te traigo un ejemplo más claro sino me entendiste!

**Acá viene el ejemplo completo**

Primero tenemos el RecyclerView

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = ItemAdapter.class.getName();
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
private Context context;



public ItemAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    items= new ArrayList<>();

}

public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items= items;
}

public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ItemAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
          Item item = items.get(position);
          holder.titulo.setText(item.getTitulo());
          holder.historia.setText(item.getHistoria());
          holder.usuario.setText(item.getUsuario());

    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error al cargar la lista. Datos incorrectos: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}



public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(Item item);

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titulo, usuario, historia;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titulo = v.findViewById(R.id.ilTitulo);
        historia = v.findViewById(R.id.ilHistoria);
        usuario = v.findViewById(R.id.ilUsuario);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mItemClickListener != null){
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClicked(items.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

//fijate que cree una interfaz para capturar el click en el item y te devuelve el item asi no tenes que mostrarlo directamente desde el Adapter y podes hacer lo que vos quieras desde afuera.

**La actividad principal donde queremos mostrar la lista**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private ItemAdapter mAdapterItem;
   private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapterItem= new ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
    RecyclerView items= findViewById(R.id.items_recyclerview);
    items.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    items.setAdapter(mAdapterItem);
            mAdapterItem.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(Item item) {
           // hace lo que quieras con tu item seleccionado
    });
}

public void readListaItems()
{
  db.collection("Historias")
        .get()
   //Al debuguear, se detiene en esta linea y salta hasta el return, dando como resultado un 0 cuando se recibe en el adaptador.
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Map<String, Object> historias = new HashMap<>();
                        historias = document.getData();
                        String titulo = (String)historias.get("Titulo");
                        String contenido = (String)historias.get("Historia");
                        String usuario = (String)historias.get("Usuario");

                        items.add(
                                new Item(
                                        titulo,
                                        contenido,
                                        usuario
                                )
                        );
                    }
                    mAdapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged(); //le avisamos al adapter que tiene nuevos elementos
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(historias.this, "No se pudo actualizar las historias porque... "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

}

Espero no olvidarme nada, pero con esas dos clases debiera andarte!

Comment: Comprendo lo que dices, solamente me confunde un poco a qué te refieres con notificar al adapter. Fuera de esto si me gustaría algún ejemplo para entenderlo un poco mejor, gracias por responder :).

Comment: rindo a las 18hs son las 09.15 ahora mismo. Cuando salgo de rendir te edito la respuesta con un ejemplo completo :)